# Training complexity of Linear SVM

Tags: time-complexity, svm, libsvm

Which is the actual computational complexity of the learning phase of SVM (let's say, that implemented in LibSVM)?

Thank you

Answer (score 17):

Training complexity of *nonlinear* SVM is generally between O(n^2) and O(n^3) with n the amount of training instances. The following papers are good references:

- [Support Vector Machine Solvers by Bottou and Lin](https://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/lin-2006.pdf)
- [SVM-optimization and steepest-descent line search by List and Simon](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~colt2009/papers/021.pdf)

PS: If you want to use linear kernel, do not use LIBSVM. LIBSVM is a general purpose (nonlinear) SVM solver. It is not an ideal implementation for linear SVM. Instead, you should consider things like [LIBLINEAR](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) (by the same authors as LIBSVM), [Pegasos](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQFjAC&url=http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00004062/01/ShalevSiSr07.pdf&ei=QCCWUYW0C8-c0wW_x4CgAw&usg=AFQjCNGng-u63xWMM2hRTGVMqRKZeJGwwA&sig2=CbV9MsSy5XqUwjPcKV_A4A&bvm=bv.46471029,d.d2k) or [SVM^perf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_perf.html). These have *much* better training complexity for linear SVM. Training speed can be orders of magnitude better than using LIBSVM.

Comment: Link 2 is dead, and for link 1 the document seems to have been removed

Comment: And what is the complexity of liblinear svm?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be heavily dependent on svm type and kernel. There is a rather technical discussion http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf.
For a quick answer, http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf, says expect it to be n^2.