# what can cause sklearn svm to hang, both cpu and mem usage are zero

Tags: scikit-learn

I have noticed very strange behaviours when using scikit learn to train a svm classifier on a dataset that has an input dimension 24700 x 11200. Once split into train/test set, the training data part after has >18500 samples.

My code looks like below:

```
def feature_scale(M):
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    return scaler.fit_transform(M)

M = feature_extraction(....) # method to create the 24700x11200 matrix
X_train_data, X_test_data, y_train, y_test = \
            train_test_split(M, self.raw_data['class'],
                             test_size=0.25,
                             random_state=42)
X_train_data=feature_scale(X_train_data) 
X_test_data =feature_scale(X_test_data) 
y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_test = y_test.astype(int)

classifier = svm.LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced', C=0.01, penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge',multi_class='ovr')

print("### test sfm...")
fs=SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced', penalty="l1", C=0.01))       
X_=fs.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
print(np.count_nonzero(X_)) # LINE C0, prints: 23828534
print(X_.shape)             # LINE C0, prints: (18587, 1282), the product is exactly 23828534
print("### end \n\n\n")

#classifier.fit(X_, y_train_data) #LINE D


print("### test kb...")
fs=SelectKBest(k=1000, score_func=f_classif)
X_=fs.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
print(np.count_nonzero(X_))  #LINE E0, prints (18587, 1000)
print(X_.shape)              #LINE E1, prints 18587000
print("### end \n\n\n")
```

M is a sparse feature matrix. Firstly I load a CSV data where each line is a sentence and there are 24700 lines (samples). Then I call a series of NLP processes to process these lines to extract features such as n-gram, pos tags, and transform the raw data in to a 24700 x m feature matrix, where m=11200 in this case. The matrix is sparse.

Observations: **(UPDATED in response to the reply - thanks for this)**

As you can see the code tests two kinds of feature selection, one using SelectFromModel, using a **LogisticRegression** algorithm; the other uses SelectKBest, using **f_classif** scoring function. I have tested both, to print the transformed feature matrix.

Both methods creates a **dense matrix where every element is filled**, the only difference is that SelectFromModel produces a matrix with 1282 features, while SelectKBest with 1000 features.

**My first question is**: why are these feature matrices fully populated? I expect them to be dense but not completely filled.

Then continue to further test the code, if I put line D back, i.e., apply svm on the SelectFromModel transformed feature matrix, the problem hangs, while both CPU and memory are 0 usage. An error is generated as below:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

However, if Line D is put back but moved to after SelectKBest, i.e., if the svm classifier uses the feature matrix created by SelectKBest, it works alright, no errors whatsoever.

**So my second question is** what difference between the two transformed feature matrices can cause that error to SVM, and why does it cause it to hang? I have **32G memory in total.**

**UPDATE**: I noticed that the server I ran experiments on had no swap. I allocated a swap of 8G, and re-run the experiment, now notice that the swap is all used: total= 8191, used=8182, free=9. I wonder if this indicates that previously there was no enough memory, and for some reason after a while the system just hangs, even system stats shows CPU and memory usage as 0?

Thanks

Comment: Relevant: [Training complexity of Linear SVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585465/training-complexity-of-linear-svm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to get small sample of you data matrix, say 1000x100 rows x features. Do all calculations with this small matrix, see if it works without errors or not.

Comment: Yes it does work. i have been developing on a smaller set and because the entire matrix causes problem now I can only test on this smaller set which works...

Comment: Ok, now try to find maximum working size of data.
When you can divide your rows, train&predict on the working sets of data and average all predictions at the end.
In case no way to be found to make original code work.

Comment: right ok... in theory this should work but the only problem is that the training only sees the partial picture of the entire dataset and there can be some divergence from a 'complete' training?

Comment: just made another update, and wonder if this indicates insufficient memory?

Comment: Yes, but you can random sample your rows and hope your data is homogeneous enought. Try it if there is no other way.
In any way all machine learning techniques expects not to many deviations in data.

Comment: And in normal case you need to make system default swap file size if you want normal system work. It's magic.

Comment: splitting data to small subsets and average over is the most practical solution to cope with insufficient memory

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing some details, especially where M is coming from. I also don't know that `util.feature_scale()` is based on, but some guessing here:

- [Memory-trashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) is the reason for a hanging-system in 99,9% of my cases!

  - Meaning: your available memory is probably completely filled and trashing will occur
  - Quite easy to analyze (in a coarse way) by observing system-statistics

So why is one approach trashing and the other is not?

- I think your original dataset might be a [sparse-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)

  - And the dense version of that matrix might be scarily big
  - 2 GB per process within your GridSearch! (will be multiplied linearily + some constants depending on job_dispatch param)
- Furthermore: **Most data-preprocessing approaches kill sparse-data!** (you will lose sparseness -> number of nonzeros increases)

  - Often: sparse-input -> dense-output (and in worst-case: still stored as sparse-matrix)
  - E.g. subtracting mean!

So:

- (1) Observe your memory
- (2) Check matrix-types and statistics (e.g. using [numpy.count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html))
- (3) Check the theory of your preprocessing

Comment: thank you, I have done more testing into this and updated my post, any feedback is highly appreciated

Comment: @Ziqi **Everything** you added/edited still points to memory-issues like i said. I even gave you a reason for the different behaviour (without analyzing your algorithms in use). So what's the problem? Work through the docs of these algorithms, check sizes between and you will understand every detail (i already hinted those steps in my answer). You probably did not even check the effects of GridSearch (which is not as trivial as expected -> job_dispatch)